# Cannot call value of non-function type [PFObject] when retriving info from parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm new to Swift and I'm learning how to use parse.com to store data an retrive it. I'm downloading an array of PFObjects from PARSE and then I need to turn it into a structure, so I created this function:

```
func queryDownload (user : PFUser) {

    let objects: [PFObject]
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Gluc")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
    do {
        objects = try query.findObjects() as [PFObject]

    } catch {
        print("ERROR")

    }
    let returnedObjects = objects {
        let elements = self.returnedObjects.count
        for i in 0...elements-1 {
            self.dataArray.append(MyData(gluc: Int(self.returnedObjects[i]["meassure"] as! String)!, fec: self.returnedObjects[i]["fec"] as! Date, alimento: self.returnedObjects[i]["alim"] as! Int, comentarios: self.returnedObjects[i]["notes"] as! String))

        }
    }

    self.dataArrayOrdered = self.dataArray.sorted(by: { $0.fec.compare($1.fec) == .orderedAscending})

    print(self.dataArrayOrdered)
}
```

But I can't run it because in this line:

```
let returnedObjects = objects {
```

It sais "Cannot call value of non-function type [PFObject]"

I'm not sure how to avoid this problem, so any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let returnedObjects = objects { ... }
```

is a syntax error, you probably wanted to *optional bind* the value

```
if let returnedObjects = objects { ... }
```

but `objects` is non-optional and optional binding is not possible.

---

Just assign the value to the variable and remove the braces

```
do {
    let objects = try query.findObjects() as [PFObject]
    let returnedObjects = objects
    let elements = self.returnedObjects.count
    for i in 0...elements-1 {
        self.dataArray.append(MyData(gluc: Int(self.returnedObjects[i]["meassure"] as! String)!, fec: self.returnedObjects[i]["fec"] as! Date, alimento: self.returnedObjects[i]["alim"] as! Int, comentarios: self.returnedObjects[i]["notes"] as! String))
    }
    self.dataArrayOrdered = self.dataArray.sorted(by: { $0.fec.compare($1.fec) == .orderedAscending})
    print(self.dataArrayOrdered)
} catch {
    print("ERROR", error)
}
```

**It's very important to put all *good* code in the `do` block and print the actual error rather than the simple literal string `"ERROR"`**

However this is Swift and there is a smarter and more convenient way using the `map` function

```
do {
    let objects = try query.findObjects() as [PFObject]
    self.dataArray = objects.map { MyData(gluc: Int($0["meassure"] as! String)!, fec: $0["fec"] as! Date, alimento: $0["alim"] as! Int, comentarios: $0["notes"] as! String) }
    self.dataArrayOrdered = self.dataArray.sorted(by: { $0.fec.compare($1.fec) == .orderedAscending})
    print(self.dataArrayOrdered)
} catch {
    print("ERROR", error)
}
```